# Turtlebot navigation in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, navigation, turtlebot, yaml, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have previously generated maps using a turtlebot, and have also used AMCL/ navigation stack in the maps. I am now trying to replicate that in Gazebo.

I have seen that turtlebot_simulator as it is doesn't work in Groovy, so I have cloned the turtlebot_gazebo repository and made a package out of it. When ran, gazebo does show a turtlebot, but it doesn't move when commanded and I don't see cmd_vel in rostopic list.

How do I go about getting the turtlebot in Gazebo and then loading my own PGM/YAML maps for navigation? Thanks in advance. I am on Ubuntu 12.04 with ROS Groovy.

Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65691/turtlebot-navigation-in-gazebo/) by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2013-06-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on 2013-11-05**:
@SaiHV i'm looking for using amcl in gazebo, have you any experience? it's my email maysam.getinfo at gmail dot com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, TurtleBot-simulation is not supported in Groovy (but planned to be ready for Hydro). If you like to use it now, I recommend you use ROS Fuerte.

To stay up to date, follow the development on Github: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SaiHV](https://answers.ros.org/users/4389/saihv/) on 2013-06-25**:
Thank you!